# emacs: How to switch off auto-indent?

Tags: assembly, emacs, indentation, auto-indent

Can anybody tell me how to switch off auto-indent in `emacs`?

What I tried is the recommended -

```
  (when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode)
    (electric-indent-mode -1))
```

In my mode-hook which does not work.  What also not work is to set `(electric-indent-mode 0)`.  And, neither does help to switch of electric indent my means of `(setq electric-indent-inhibit t)`.

What is the right approach?

Comment: electric-indent-mode is enabled by default only since Emacs 24.4. It is a global minor mode so it doesn't make much sense to use it in a major-mode hook. You can simply toggle any minor mode via M-x foo-mode. You can use C-h f foo-mode to learn how to control it in Lisp. I don't understand what do you mean by "not work", C-h v foo-mode tells the variable is nil after M-: (foo-mode -1)?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? Normally, setting `electric-indent-inhibit` to `t` should inhibit it in the current buffer.

Comment: It's for editing assembly sources.  What I want is that I determine indenting explicitly because I am using different assembly dialects and such.  Starting from `emacs -Q foo.s` (which triggers "Assembler" mode for me), when I enter `text<RET>` it should just add a newline without any indentation gaga. Same for labels, same for comments, etc.

Comment: Related: [How to set Emacs up for assembly programming and fix indentation?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38672928)

Answer (score 4):

For `nasm-mode`, I simply call `(electric-indent-local-mode -1)` in my mode hook, which should be enough.

For `asm-mode`, it by default binds <kbd>RET</kbd> to `newline-and-indent`, so you can redefine the key to `(define-key asm-mode-map (kbd "RET") #'newline)` and disable `electric-indent-local-mode` in your mode hook.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This works -- almost.  What remains is: `label:<RET>` and emacs will add extra blanks after the ":" so that I get superfluous, trailing blanks and a line like "label:<SPC><SPC><SPC><SPC>".

Comment: for that, `(define-key asm-mode-map ":" nil)`

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem with ''':'''.  Unfortunately, there is still some automatism going on:  When I type a ```@```, then position the cursor on it and press ```TAB```, it adds 32 or so blanks before the ```@``` and the ```@``` occurs somewhere in the middle of a line.